# An implication of the inequality $|h \cdot \nabla g(x)| \leq |g(x + h) - g(x)| +C|h|^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose that $g \in C^2(K)$ with $K \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ compact such that
$$|h \cdot \nabla g(x)| \leq |g(x + h) - g(x)| +C|h|^2,$$
where $|h| \leq 1$ and $C > 0$. For $\theta > 0$ and $p > 1$, it is possible to show that
$$|h \cdot \nabla g(x)|^p \leq (1 + \theta)|g(x + h) - g(x)|^p + C(\theta)|h|^{2p },$$
for some constant $C(\theta)$?

Note: I believe this is an easy inequality, but I haven't been able to verify it yet.